# Sikuli compiled jar file script running on other pc (requirements)

Tags: java, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I could not find clear answer to this, I would need to know what is needed to run compiled sikuli script on other computer.I have a sikuli jar script that I transferred to one of our pcs at work and I expected this to run since I sucessfully installed JDK 12 there and that was the java version I did the coding on.

However, the jar gives me no response when I double-click it. I know that many things could be involved in this error but first I would like to cross out the basics.

So, my questions are:

1. Do I need sikuli IDE on that pc too in order to run it?
2. Do I need Eclipse/NetBeans installed along with it?
3. What is the standard procedure when moving sikuli scripts to work on other computers?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `java -jar youjarfile.jar` ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" FindFailed.....A/JPG dadada.  Does this mean that I have to have pictures on the other pc as well to run it? I though these would get compiled inside the jar.

Comment: Something is wrong with your jar file. Go over the exception trace and find out why you get that exception and fix it. If your app looking for some resources like files or property there are good chances it's not embedded in jar file.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the .jar of Sikuli. They are just not standalone jars. They need a Sikuli environment + the doc is written by ppl who know, but don't explain it well.